# How does updating SPFx webparts/extensions work between tenant wide/non-tenant wide deployment models?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I am trying to understand the difference between deploying spfx customizations between tenant wide and non tenant wide (and differences when updating/not updating the version number). Per my current knowledge, I understand this so far

**Tenant Wide:**

Once you overwrite the solution, it updates everywhere automatically. This is true when keeping the version number the same.

If version number is increased, what happens here?

**Non Tenant Wide:**

If you overwrite the solution, it updates everywhere. This is true when keeping the version number the same. However for some webparts like listview command sets, it requires the app to be deleted from each site and its recycle bin, and needs an increase version number when adding to app catalogue.

If version number is increased, then apps will get a message on each site saying there is an update, and requires a manual update to fully update. While this is not done, only the static resources portion of the app will get the update automatically. Any manifest config-like changes won't take effect until it is manually updated.

Can anyone confirm if these details are correct, or if there is anything more to be added?

Thanks